# How can I change the resolution in Emergency 2014?

Tags: monitor, emergency-2014

Emergency 2014 allows only to select screen resolutions in 4:3 ratios.

How can I set it to the native resolution of my monitor, 1920x1080?

Comment: @stizzle84 No, I figured it out easily myself. It's not that obvious for everyone, so I wanted to make it easier for others wo have the same problem.

Comment: Oh ok @Gerald schneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the resolution by editing the configuration file. The file is located in `%localappdata%\Quadriga Games\Emergency 2014` (just copy&paste this in the address bar of your Explorer window).

Open `em2014.cfg` with a text editor that can handle unix line breaks, e.g. Notepad++ or WordPad, it will not look pretty in the windows Notepad.

Edit these lines:

```
<var name="start_resolution_x" value="1920" />
<var name="start_resolution_y" value="1080" />
```

Save the file, launch the game.